# How to make sure a block of Script runs first, before the next block?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

sorry if this is an elementary question, but I just can't get this to work the way I need.

I have a script that essentially consists of 3 parts:

1). Removes all protection in a sheet

2). Executes some copying functions (since ranges are protected I need to remove the protection first #1)

3). Sets the protection back up after #2 is finished.

Here's my code:

First clears protection

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('COST REPORT');
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
    }
}
```

Second clears data in cells

```
 var costReport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
     'COST REPORT');
 costReport.getRange('F12:F16').clearContent(); //Theoreticals
 costReport.getRange('D20:D20').clearContent(); //Week Ending Date

 Third sets protection

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('COST REPORT');
 var costReportCOGS = ss.getRange('G11:G16');
 var protection = costReportCOGS.protect().setDescription('costReportCOGS');
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
 var costReportPurchaseEnding = ss.getRange('D11:E16');
 var protection = costReportPurchaseEnding.protect().setDescription(
     'costReportPurchaseEnding');
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
```

I've cut some of the script down for ease of debugging, but basically I need the script to Execute & Finish in this order, one by one. If you just try running the script the way it is, the protection doesn't get removed and I get the error "trying to edit protected range...."

If I run each block by itself then it works perfect, but that consists of 3 different scripts the user has to run and I need it all in one.

Thanks in advance!

Sean.

Something like this?

```
        function removeProtection() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('COST REPORT');
    var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    }
};

function clearRangeData() {
var costReport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
         'COST REPORT');
     costReport.getRange('F12:F16').clearContent(); //Theoreticals
     costReport.getRange('D20:D20').clearContent(); //Week Ending Date
};
function weeklyFileRangeProtection() {
  //COST REPORT
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('COST REPORT');
  var costReportCOGS = ss.getRange('G11:G16');
  var protection = costReportCOGS.protect().setDescription('costReportCOGS');
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
};
```

Comment: Are any of the function calls you're making asynchronous where they don't finish immediately and would have an option for a callback function that tells you when they have completed?

Comment: Synchronous operations all run in order. Asynchronous operations are started when you call them, but they finish at some arbitrary time later. They should all have a callback function, and you sequence things by starting the next operation in the previous callback.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, they do not finish immediately. The script seems like it wants to run the entire thing all at once.

Comment: Sean, we're asking you (not telling you this is so) if any any of the functions you are calling are asynchronous and don't finish immediately because that could be one cause of what you're seeing?

Comment: @Barmar could you give me an example of this? How do I call them one after the other?

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, so how do I get each part to finish before the next one starts? Is that possible?

Comment: Generically: `func1(..., function() { func2(..., function() { func3(...); }); })`. The `...` are the arguments telling the function what to process, and the last argument is the callback that starts the next operation.

Comment: Sean, first you investigate if any of the functions you are calling are asynchronous and if so, you find out how to pass them a callback which will tell you when they are done.

Comment: Something like:
     function removeProtection() { .....};
     function clearDataRange() {........};
     function setProtection() {.....};

?

Comment: When I page through the APIs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getProtections(ProtectionType)), I'm not seeing that you're using async APIs so that may not be the issue.

Comment: I've written these in 3 separate functions, so would I simply copy and past the entire function one after the other?

Comment: Sean, folks have just been hypothesizing about an issue with asynchronous functions.  Nobody has yet identified one that could be the issue and thus could fix your issue so there's nothing yet to change on that accord.  I looked into the APIs and don't see where that issue would be occurring.  I would suggest looking into whether there is a script error that is causing your script to stop execution part way through.  If the error occurred near the end of one of the first two blocks that could explain why manually running each piece separately works.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 I've updated a portion of the script, would something like that work?

This way it runs each function individually first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having issues because for each function you are calling `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet` . Each time you make this call you create a virtual "copy" of the spreadhseet, and the changes you make to this copy are only passed to the version in Google's servers once the whole script is finished. Hence, if you manually run each of the 3 function that the workflow:

Run function 1 -> script finished -> update the spreadsheet in the server -> run function 2 (which now gets the updated spreadsheet) -> script finished -> update the spreadsheet in the server -> run function 3 (which now gets the re-updated spreadsheet) -> script finished -> update the spreadsheet in the server

Now, if you run the three functions, the way the script is here is what happens:

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('COST REPORT');` this creates a virtual copy of the spreadsheet -> your code removes the protection from this copy and the server spreadsheet is not modified -> you call again `var costReport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('COST REPORT');` which create a new copy of the server spreadsheet, which hadn't its protections removed yet -> your code tries to clear the data on this copy, which triggers the error.

As @Cameron Roberts suggested in his answer `Spreadsheet.flush()` between the calls will solve the issue, because if forces the changes to be synced to the spreadsheet in the server. But you will have another "problem", which is the amount of copies you are calling, the `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is very time consuming! It is better if you make only one call, store in a variable (you already do that, it is your variable `ss`) and make all the edits to that.

Your code will end up looking like this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var costReport = ss.getSheetByName('COST REPORT');

//First clear protection

var protections = costReport.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
    };
};

//Second clears data in cells

costReport.getRange('F12:F16').clearContent(); //Theoreticals
costReport.getRange('D20:D20').clearContent(); //Week Ending Date

//Third sets protection

 var costReportCOGS = costReport.getRange('G11:G16');
 var protection = costReportCOGS.protect().setDescription('costReportCOGS');
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 };
 var costReportPurchaseEnding = costReport.getRange('D11:E16');
 var protection = costReportPurchaseEnding.protect().setDescription(
     'costReportPurchaseEnding');
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 };
```

This method also applies to Google Docs, which does NOT have a similar `.flush()` method for updating the server version.

Comment: Okay thank you, this makes perfect sense! I am going to try this out later on today and I will let you know the result. Thank you for explaining this to me and for the breakdown

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have misdiagnosed the issue slightly. The code is already running in the correct order, but the protection is simply not being removed before the write calls are executed, due to the nature of Google's underlying architecture.

The comments steering you towards asynchronous behaviour are not helpful in this case, they do make sense from a Javascript perspective but are not the issue here, this is an Apps Script / Google Sheets issue, none of the functions you are calling are asynchronous.

I have two suggestions, one is to try calling `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after the protections are removed.  The other is to use `Utilities.sleep()` to artificially pause the script for a brief period after executing the remove() calls.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)